# Can use @current_user in view but not controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can do

```
<p>Welcome <%= @current_user.login %></p>
    <% @comments.each do |comments| %>
    <h3><%= comments.body %></h3>
    <% end %>
```

but not

```
@cuser = @current_user
@user = User.find(params[:user_id]) 
@user.comments.create(:user_id => @user.id, :commenter => @cuser.login,  :body => params[:comment][:body])
respond_to do |format| 
     format.js 
     format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'Comment was successfully created.') }
```

Which gives  the error "undefined method `login' for nil:NilClass"

If I can use @current_user in one instance why not the other

Comment: Do you use `devise` gem?

Comment: I'm interested in where you get value of `current_user`. Is there any method? Something other?

Comment: def current_user
        return unless session[:user_id]
        @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
     end

Answer (score 5):

Use `current_user` instead of `@current_user` in both the view and the controller.

You probably have a `current_user` method on your ApplicationController. That method is creating the `@current_user` variable you use in the view.

It is a common practice to use `current_user` in both the view and the controller. To check the login, just do `current_user.login`. That will work.

Comment: This is from my ApplicationController   def current_user
        return unless session[:user_id]
        @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
     end

Comment: Could this be anything to do with routes?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Don't use `@cuser` in the controller, just use `current_user` wherever you want

Answer (score 1):

Replace `@current_user` with `current_user`.

It seems, you call `current_user` method in controller. `current_user` create an instance variable for controller `@current_user`. That's why you can see this variable in the view.

You'll catch an error in the views if you'll remove all `current_user` method callings in the controller action